# Liberation Script - is it really another Liberation font by Steve Mattison?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Yesterday, just out of curiosity, I googled for Liberation Script and to my surprise this font seems do exists:

- https://www.cdnfonts.com/liberation-script.font
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_fonts

Is it really created by Steve Matteson or somehow authorized by him?

I cannot find any mentions about it on the web.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Why not ask him?  There's a contact link [on his webpage](https://mattesontypographics.com/)

Comment: Yeah, since there are no answers yet, this is what I will probably do.

Comment: I had a look in the font file code. It says the font is copyright of Monotype but does also mention Steve Matteson as the author. However, this doesn't sound right at all, since all the Liberation fonts are SIL Open fonts as far as I'm aware. And the font available on the site you linked to has no licence file associated with it. I can't find the font listed on the Monotype website either. That's highly suspicious in my opinion.

Comment: Also the official [Liberation fonts distribution page on github](https://github.com/liberationfonts/liberation-fonts/wiki) makes no mention of such a font. The release page is here: https://github.com/liberationfonts/liberation-fonts/releases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sent a mail to Steve few days ago, and here is an abridged version of his answer:

> The Liberation Script is an un-authorized copy of
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/ink-free which I made [...]. Because the Microsoft version has a special license it’s possible that someone asked for permission to do it but I don’t know. It’s odd that they call it Liberation Script since it really has no relationship to Liberation Sans and Serif (I would have designed something different!).

So it has no real relation to Liberation fonts.

Comment: That was a great outcome, thanks for sharing.